# How to call an ASMX web service via GET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a webservice defined here:

/app/AutocompleteManager.asmx

```
[WebMethod]
public string AutocompleteComposers()
{
  return "hey, what's up";
}
```

I want to call it using the GET method with extra parameters.

If I just go `/app/AutocompleteManager.asmx?q=something`, it won't work because I don't have the action specified.

If I go `/app/AutocompleteManager.asmx/AutocompleteComposers?q=something` it breaks.

Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your web.config like so:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
              <add name="HttpSoap"/> 
              <add name="HttpPost"/>
              <add name="HttpGet"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Use GET. Isn't that what you're question is about?

Comment: it wasn't obvious that I will be able to go /app/AutocompleteManager.asmx/AutocompleteComposers? ... (which for the record is now the URL I have to call)

Comment: I don't think that <add name="HttpSoap"/>  is necessary.  It seems to work just fine for a simple get with out it.

Answer (score -1):

Get needs to enabled. Check that first.

Comment: What do you mean? How would I do this?

Comment: Please provide an example